# type `*structpb.Struct` has no field or method `Unmarshal`, `Size` and `MarshalToSizedBuffer`

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am using protocol buffer to define a struct -

```
message MyData {
string id = 1;
google.protobuf.Struct json_field = 2;
}
```

After compiling the `proto` file with `protoc`, I get three undefined functions on `json_field` -

```
  Error: m.JsonField.MarshalToSizedBuffer undefined (type *structpb.Struct has no field or method MarshalToSizedBuffer) (typecheck)
  Error: m.JsonField.Size undefined (type *structpb.Struct has no field or method Size) (typecheck)
  Error: m.JsonField.Unmarshal undefined (type *structpb.Struct has no field or method Unmarshal) (typecheck)
```

Snippet from `.pb.go` file -

```
if m.JsonField != nil {
        {
            size, err := m.JsonField.MarshalToSizedBuffer(dAtA[:i])
            if err != nil {
                return 0, err
            }
            i -= size
            i = encodeVarintIlo(dAtA, i, uint64(size))
        }
        i--
        dAtA[i] = 0x7a
    }
```

I'm not sure how to go about this since the `.pb.go` file is auto-generated on compilation.

Appreciate any pointers regarding this.

Comment: I think you may be incorrectly mixing gogo/protobuf and google.golang.org/protobuf. gogo/protobuf includes `MarshalToSizedBuffer` but Google's library does not. Please include your `protoc` command. You may want to check to ensure you're installing Google's `protoc-gen-go` (google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go)

Comment: @DazWilkin Thank you for your comment. The `proto` command that I'm using is wrapped in a shell script and looks like it is using `gogo/protobuf`


```protoc -I=. --gogofaster_out=plugins=grpc,paths=source_relative:. "${FILE}"```

Comment: @DazWilkin I'm not sure how to go about from here? If I'm using `gogo/protobuf` to generate the `.pb.go` definitions shouldn't it have included `MarshalToSizedBuffer`?

Comment: If you want to use gogo, see https://github.com/gogo/protobuf#more-speed-and-more-generated-code. You'll need to add the following `Mgoogle/protobuf/struct.proto=github.com/gogo/protobuf/types,` into the `--gogofaster_out` flag